# Creating own List replica in Scala

Tags: scala

I am reading Functional Programming in Scala from Manning, authored by Paul Chiusano and Runar Bjarnason. In its 3rd chapter, there is a code to create a List and there are assignments to implement various methods of the list. Following is partial implementation of the my List

```
package src.Cons

sealed trait List[+A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](h:A, t:List[A]) extends List[A]

object List {

//my issue is I do not want to pass a list to sum but want to use objectName.sum notation
      def sum(ints:List[Int]):Int = ints match {
        case Nil => 0
        case Cons(x,xs) => x+sum(xs)
      }
    }
```

Question - How can I create my list such that I can call `l.sum` instead of `List.sum(l)`?

Answer (score 3):

You can "PmL", as @Gabriele Petronella has suggested, or you can move the `sum()` method to the `Cons` class, as @DeadNight wrote, but before either of those can work you have to resolve the current conflict between your `List` object and your `List` trait.

The `sum()` in your `List` object can only sum a `List[Int]` but your class definitions use a more generic type member and, as such, you can't use `+` because the compiler doesn't know how to add two `A` types.

If you want to restrict your `List` to only handling numeric types then this will work.

```
case class Cons[A: Numeric](h:A, t:List[A]) extends List[A] {
  def sum: A = List.sum(this)
}

object List {
  def sum[A](ints:List[A])(implicit ev: Numeric[A]):A = ints match {
    case Nil => ev.zero
    case Cons(x,xs) => ev.plus(x, sum(xs))
  }
}
val x = Cons(4, Cons(2, Nil))
x.sum  // res0: Int = 6
```

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov, I agree that restricting the `sum()` to numerics is probably preferable rather than restricting the entire `List` structure to numerics, but that doesn't make my posing "not quite right", just not the only solution.

Answer (score 3):

## Making `sum` a member

The problem is, you don't know how to sum the `List[A]` for every type `A`, only a `List[Int]`. If there was a way to allow calls when `A` is an `Int`...

Let's take a look at the standard library for that. We're interested in [Option#flatten method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/Option.html#flatten[B](implicitev:%3C:%3C[A,Option[B]]):Option[B]) because:

```
val o1 = Option(Option(3)).flatten // compiles
val o2 = Option(4).flatten // does not compile
```

Notice the weird `implicit ev: <:<[A, Option[B]]`. This is the key here - it's a thing that compiler provides for you, but only if it is known at compile time, that your `Option[A]` is a subtype of `Option[Option[B]]` for some type `B`. This is the trick that we can use.

```
sealed trait List[+A] {
  def sum(implicit ev: A <:< Int): Int = this match {
    case Nil => 0
    case Cons(x, xs) => x + xs.sum // <- here x is magically converted to Int, so we can use plus
  }
}
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](h:A, t:List[A]) extends List[A]

println(Cons(4, Cons(38, Nil)).sum) // 42
```

[ScalaFiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/1tQ8kvG/0)

Notice that you can write `<:<[A, B]` as `A <:< B`.

NB: there's also `=:=[A, B]` type, for when your `A` is exactly `Int` - you can use either of those

## Doing better?

Actually, std library has `sum` method and it's type is even weirder:
`def sum(implicit ev: Numeric[A])`. Doing so allows it to work on any number-like type like `Double` and `Int`, and has the operations for comparison, subtraction, multiplication, etc. So you can make it even more generic. I suggest you do it after reading a chapter about Monoids, tho :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the so-called ["Pimp my Library"](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766) pattern.

Define an implicit class `ListOps`

```
implicit class ListOps[+A](list: List[A]) {
  def sum = List.sum(this)
}
```

and now you can call `list.sum`. The implicit conversion will be triggered and the compiler will interpret it as `ListOps(list).sum`.

Answer (score 0):

## Move the definition of sum inside the definition of List trait

You can leave the concrete definitions to Nil & Cons

```
package src.Cons

sealed trait List[+A] {
  def sum: Int
}

case object Nil extends List[Nothing] {
  val sum: Int = 0
}

case class Cons[+A](h:A, t:List[A]) extends List[A] {
  def sum: Int = h + t.sum
}
```